# Seifert-van-Kampen theorem for groupoid and group

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

We know two versions of Seifert-van-Kampen theorem, one for fundamental groupoids and the other for groups. How do these two relate to each other? I know that the case for groups can be derived from the case for groupoids by treating $\pi_1$ as a groupoid.

But what does this mean in a "practical" sense? I've seen some cases where people use the following diagram

$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} \Pi(S^1) @>{\Pi(f)}>> \Pi(S^1)\\ @V{}VV @VV{j}V\\ 1 @>>{}> \Pi(X)\end{CD}$$

to conclude that

$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} \pi_1(S^1, 1) @>{\pi_1(f)}>> \pi_1(S^1, 1)\\ @V{}VV @VV{\pi_1(j)}V\\ 1 @>>{}> \pi_1(X, 1)\end{CD}$$

without appealing to the group version of Seifert-van-Kampen. Why are we allowed to do this? And why do we need to go from the groupoid version first instead of just using the group version?

The only reasons I could think of are: we don't need to take care of base points by using groupoids and the requirements for the theorem are easier since we don't need connectedness. But I'm quite unsure, any feedback would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Hi, I realize gruppoid is a proper spelling in German, but I swapped it to "groupoid" to be consistent with the English in the rest of the post.  Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @rschwieb ah right sorry I thought we had the same term in english, thanks btw!

Comment: @rschwieb You missed the title! :-)

Comment: @JeremyRickard doh

Comment: Are you saying the first square you drew is a pushout  square and wondering why the second one is as well? Are there any hypotheses on $f$ or $X$ or $j$?

Comment: @FShrike Yes the first square is a pushout and I'm wondering why we can deduce that the second square is a pushout, and no that's all the hypotheses we have, $f, j$ are just maps in the pushout square.

Comment: Perhaps think natural transformation

Comment: @AksharaPrasad could you elaborate? thanks

Comment: If, in the last paragraph, you're asking for motivation for using the fundamental groupoids instead of fundamental groups, I think Grothendieck provides an example in his essay "Sketch of a Programme".  It mostly went above my head when I read it, so I'm not confident enough to write a proper answer and explain it. The essay has a translation to English, thankfully.

Comment: @NG_ could you provide me a link? Thanks!

Comment: Sure - [https://matematicas.unex.es/~navarro/res/esquisseeng.pdf ].

Comment: Wait a second. Why should $f$ take $1\mapsto1$? Why should $j$ take $1\mapsto 1$? I feel like there's missing context. Where'd you see a diagram like this?

Comment: @FShrike $f$ was meant to be the identity mapping, and there's another function $g : S^1 \mapsto D^2$, but $D^2$ deformation retracts to just a point, so we have $1$ in the pushout grupoid. $j$ is the mapping we get from the pushout.

Comment: That doesn’t make sense. The pushout of $1\longleftarrow G=G$ is just $1$. Is there an actual general phenomenon you want, eg something like, “pushouts are *always* preserved once you take fundamental groups”, or something?

Comment: @FShrike could you elaborate why it doesn't make sense? And yes that's the general phenomenon that I'm interested in, I was just taking an example with $S^1$

Comment: Because $\Pi(X)$ would be forced to be the trivial groupoid (if I'm not mistaken) and the question would be uninteresting. As an example it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @FShrike I see, I'm interested in the general usage of the theorem (for groupoid) and how we can (in practice) use Seifert-van-Kampen for grupoids but at some point change it to fundamental groups, what are the requirements for us to be allowed to do this?

Comment: @hteica Off the top of my head, I don’t know. ‘Topology and Groupoids’ by Brown is likely a good reference (the author was one of the original proponents for the use of groupoids in topology)

Comment: @FShrike thanks, I'll definitely take a look.